# Git dependency with npm keeping .git files

Tags: npm

I am using a private GIT repository as dependency in npm:

```
"name": "git+ssh://git@git.domain.com:user/repo.git"
```

This is working and clones the repository inside `node_modules` when I do `npm install`.

The matter is it deletes `.git` folder and `.gitignore` file. I want to keep those file (to do commits later) ¿How to keep those files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm install private git repository without .git folder and .gitignore file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30842981/npm-install-private-git-repository-without-git-folder-and-gitignore-file)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It sounds like you would be better served keeping a local checkout of the project and specifying the dependency with a local path.

```
cd ..
git clone ssh://git@git.domain.com:user/repo.git
cd repo; npm install
cd ../PROJECT
npm i --save ../repo
```

That way you can make changes and commit them back.

`npm` treats the contents of `node_modules` as private, so you should not expect to be able to get into the node_modules directory and do anything useful.  If you want to maintain a git checkout of a project which is a dependency, then do that, but don't combine it with the dependency-management that npm does.

Also check out `npm link` if the dependency is itself a npm-compatible package. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use `npm link ../path-to-local-git` after you git clone your dependency repo.

```
git clone <repo>
cd PROJECT
npm link ../<repo>
```

and you see the build process run.