# npm install private git repository with .git folder and .gitignore file

Tags: git, npm

I am using npm to download a private git repository with `npm install` command. However, the downloaded repository does not contain a .git folder or a .gitignore file. Is there any way that I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

`npm install` does not install git files.

Comment: Is there any other ways that I can download .git folder only after npm install  finished?

Comment: git clone <repo> instead?

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to generate .git folder and .gitignore via git command. I write the script in **postinstall** field of package.json. Here is my example of **package.json**.

```
...
"dependencies": {
    "test": "git+ssh://git@private-git-repo.com/repo.git"
},
"scripts": {
    "start": "npm config set tmp `pwd`",
    "postinstall": "cd node_module/repo && mv .npmignore .gitignore && git clone --no-checkout repo && mv repo/.git/ .git/ && git read-tree --reset HEAD && rm -r repo"
}
...
```

Then first I run *npm start* to setup npm tmp config, then I run *npm install* to generate .git folder and .gitignore file back.

However, I encounter another problem that the content of downloaded package.json will change with add more content like "_id", "_resolved", "_from", etc. Not knowing how to solve this problem now.